# Pandas Add missing Row based on Monthly values

Tags: pandas

Is there a simple way to add rows to a Dataframe for missing monthly values?

In this case there is not row for 2016-05 and 2016-06.

```
                 a      b       c          d  ...     
month                                                                           

2015-12-31       0   6615        0      2730  ...       
2016-01-31       0 -13508        0      7120  ...        
2016-02-29       0   2394        0      1660  ...    
2016-03-31       0      7        0       694  ...        
2016-04-30       0      7        0      6445  ... 

// missing months

2016-07-30       0      0        0         0  ...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your index "months" are datetime objects already, then you can re-index your dataframe to all the month ends between your start date and end date.

```
dates = pd.date_range('20151231','20160730',freq='M') 
out = df.reindex(dates)

# you'll now have NaNs for the new months that were missing
# you can fill them in with 0s if you'd like that better
out.fillna(0.,inplace=True)
```

Comment: this works great if there is missing months but if there are not any missing months - I get this:  ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Answer (score 0):

Generate date range using `pd.date_range` and then `reindex`

```
>>> df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1],freq='M').tolist() + [d
f.index[-1]])
>>> df
              a
date
2015-12-31  0.0
2016-01-31  0.0
2016-02-29  0.0
2016-03-31  0.0
2016-04-30  0.0
2016-05-31  NaN
2016-06-30  NaN
2016-07-30  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If dates are not your index you can create and merge a new dataframe with [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) month-ends.

```
completedates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='12/1/2015', end='7/31/2016', freq='M'), columns=['month'])
completedates.merge(df, how='left', on='month')
```

or in one line

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='12/1/2015', end='7/31/2016', freq='M'), columns=['month']).merge(df, how='left', on='month')
```